# Bintray, remove folder in package

Tags: bintray

I have a maven package that contains multiple packages. I would like to delete subpackage in it but I can't find out how to do this.

You can delete file from package in Bintray UI or use rest api method

```
DELETE /content/:subject/:repo/:file_path
```

But what if i want to delete whole package? Why there is no support for this?

Answer (score 6):

You can delete your package using the [Delete Package](https://bintray.com/docs/api/#url_delete_package) REST API.

There are many more REST API calls in [Bintray REST API](https://bintray.com/docs/api/) page.

<sup>I am with [JFrog](http://jfrog.com), the company behind [bintray](/questions/tagged/bintray) and [artifactory](/questions/tagged/artifactory).</sup>

Comment: I want to delete folder in package but keep other folders. This api method deletes whole package. I would like to have method DELETE /packages/:subject/:repo/:package/:folder_path

Comment: In order to remove a specific path you'll need to remove all artifacts under that specific path

Comment: This is not pragmatic way to delete all files in folder in order to delete folder itself :/

Comment: Not to mention there is no UI button for simply deleting whole directory... :/

Comment: Please how can I deploy a path to another package in the same repository ? I want to keep the artifactId